# concatenation two fields in xsl

Tags: xslt

I have a some xml fields i need to concatenate all the fields in one field

```
<fields>
<field name="first"><value>example</value></field>
<field name="last"><value>hello</value></field>
<field name="age"><value>25</value></field>
<field name="enable"><value>1</value></field>
<fields>
```

i need to transform as following

```
<fields>
<field name="all"><value>example hello 25 1</value></field>
</field>
```

with space delimiter using XSL

Comment: How should `value` elements be handled that do not contain text? Should that result in three spaces or in only one? I.e. `example   25` or `example 25`?

Comment: If the value element is null there should not be any space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This short and simple (no explicit conditional instructions) XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <fields>
    <field name="all">
      <xsl:variable name="vfieldConcat">
        <xsl:for-each select="field/value">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <value><xsl:value-of select=
         "normalize-space($vfieldConcat)"/></value>
    </field>
  </fields>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document (corrected for well-formedness):**

```
<fields>
    <field name="first">
        <value>example</value>
    </field>
    <field name="last">
        <value>hello</value>
    </field>
    <field name="age">
        <value>25</value>
    </field>
    <field name="enable">
        <value>1</value>
    </field>
</fields>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<fields>
   <field name="all">
      <value>example hello 25 1</value>
   </field>
</fields>
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <fields>
    <field name="all">
      <value><xsl:value-of select="field/value"/></value>
    </field>
  </fields>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced:**

```
<fields>
   <field name="all">
      <value>example hello 25 1</value>
   </field>
</fields>
```

**Explanation**: Using the fact that the default value for the **[`separator` attribute of `xsl:value-of`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#value-of)** is a single space.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
...
<fields>
<field name="all">
    <value><xsl:apply-templates select="fields/field"/></value>
</field>
</fields>
...
<xsl:template match="field[value/text()]">
  <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
  <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
...
```

Comment: I think this would work if the space in your `xsl:if` was either put in a `xsl:value-of` or `xsl:text`.