# Can we use xsl:strip-space in xsl:copy-of function?

Tags: xml, xslt

My input XML:

```
<sb:author>

   <ce:given-name>

      A.

    </ce:given-name>

     <ce:surname>

       Bernal

     </ce:surname>

</sb:author>
```

desired output XML:

```
<sb:author>

  <ce:given-name>A.</ce:given-name>

  <ce:surname>Bernal</ce:surname>

</sb:author>
```

In my XSL I used

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="ce:given-name ce:surname"/> 

<xsl:copy-of select="normalize-space(sb:author)" />
```

but it does not work. Can anyone help me to remove this spaces?

Comment: possible duplicate of [concatenation two fields in xsl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215605/concatenation-two-fields-in-xsl)

Comment: if you use `copy-of` it would just clone the nodes, with the spaces also being copied.

Comment: `strip-space` only strips text nodes that are _entirely_ whitespace.  Text nodes that include any non-whitespace characters are not affected.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the identity transform and add this template:

```
<xsl:template name="text()[normalize-space() != '']">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score -2):

use these in combo:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
```